# DB2 systemd startup

Tags: redhat, systemd, selinux, ibm, db2

I have a DB2 systemd startup unit that is being denied by SELinux. Here is the unit:

[Unit]
Description=IBM DB2
After=network.service

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/user/home/dvdxadm1/sqllib/db2profile
ExecStart=/user/home/dvdxadm1/sqllib/adm/db2start
ExecStop=/user/home/dvdxadm1/sqllib/adm/db2stop force
User=dvdxadm1
Group=db2iadm1
Restart=always
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGHUP

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

This fails with several AVC denials, and I have tried several "audit2allow" statements in an attempt to alleviate. Does anyone have a straightforward way to get DB2 working under SELinux without turning it permissive?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by modifying the unit to run after systemd-logind and then ran audit2allow -a -M db2.pp

semodule -i db2.pp

This fixed it.